# NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse Apache TIKA

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying to read an excel file using TIKA in windows eclipse and getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/OpenXML4JException
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:82)
    at ExcelFile.ExcelFile.main(ExcelFile.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I have read another post similar to this and added below jars in eclipse build path

dom4j
log4j
tika-core
tika-parsers
xmlbeans

Thanks for your help.
SN

Comment: Apache Tika has a large number of dependencies - what tool are you using to add them to your build?

Comment: Hello, I am using eclipse in windows

Comment: And how are you telling Eclipse what dependencies to add? Manually? M2Eclipse? Other?

Comment: I am running it manually in eclipse for learning purpose.

Comment: I did not understand clearly what you meant by dependencies...you mean dependent jar files? I added them manually to build path

Comment: And how did you ensure you added all of the right ones?

Comment: after adding all required jars, the errors shown in red color is gone in eclipse